# Scalding TypedType[Set[MyObject]] to TypedType[MyObject]

Tags: java, scala, scalding

In my Scalding Flow I have a `TypedType[Set[MyObject]]`. How do I flatten it to a `TypedType[MyObject]`?

Answer (score 1):

`pipe.flatMap(identity)` should do it